# Suggest that Googlebot read "dezign" as "design"

Tags: domains, keywords, googlebot, spelling

I used the spelling "dezign" instead of "design" many times in my website -- even in my domain name.

Is there any way to suggest that Googlebot read "dezign" word as "design" with correct spelling?

Comment: Google may see it as a typo and try to correct but other than that its trying to rank for banannas but spelling it as strawberrys

Comment: I agree with @bybe. It is possible to use special brand keywords (like a company name), but there's not really any way to tell Google, "Hey, this thing that looks like a misspelling is actually a proper word." I know the 'z' makes it sound cool, but it's not going to let you create a new word that only you rank for. Context matters, though. If you constantly use it the way you would use the word design, you're not going to get anywhere; however, if dezign has a very different special meaning, you might be able to get away with it. Otherwise, do what Hagen Daas did & make up a new, crazy word.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do what you ask. There are a number of companies out there who's brands are based on mis-spelling common words and they aren't able to do it either. Google will have the page rank for dezign but every time a user tries to search for dezign the SERP will say "did you mean design? showing you results for "design" instead. and the end user will need to clicck on the link tht says "Show me results for dezign".